# How to get the processor number on android

Tags: android

Hi all， I want to get the processor number on android. can I do that like as follow:

```
int processporNum =  sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
```

but everytime the return value is 1 on some of my phones, so i not sure this methold is right .is there anyother api can get this info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can run

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

Comment: This returns the number of CPU's available for THIS specific virtual machine, as I experienced. That may not be what you want, still, for a few purposes this is very handy. You can test this really easily: Kill all apps, run the above code. Open 10 very intensive apps, and then run the test again. Sure, this will only work on a multi cpu device, I guess.

Comment: @blackbelt: what is the c way to get CPU cores？ what's the head file of Runtime class? Is the Runtime class here belong to java

Comment: If device has, for example 4 powerful and 4 low-power cores, it will return 8, however, only 4 cores are available.

Answer (score 5):

I see you're using native code.

So read file /proc/cpuinfo and interpret is accordingly.
It looks something like this:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 162.83
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon 
CPU implementer : 0x51
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0x00f
CPU revision    : 2
Hardware    : htcleo
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```