# How to get cpu number in android and windows phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, processor

I am going to write multi-thread process speed calculator that calculates something and gets the result for windows phone and android however first of all before i create threads i have to know how many cpus' does phone have.Can anyone know how can i get the number of the cpus or does anyone can give me and advice ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593829/how-to-get-the-processor-number-on-android or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7962155/435706
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400045/how-to-get-the-number-of-processors-on-windows-phone


please search before you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting CPU count in android use this:

android_getCpuCount()  from [cpufeatures](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html) NDK library works correctly.